# Solr Suggester - How do I filter autocomplete results

Tags: solr, autocomplete, search-suggestion

I want to filter the auto complete results from my suggester
Lets say I have a book table

```
Table (Id Guid, BookName String, BookOwner id)
```

I want each user to get a list to autocomplete from its own books.

I want to add something like the

```
http://.../solr/vault/suggest?q=c&fq=BookOwner:3
```

This doesnt work.
What other ways do I have to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Solr Spell Check is a completely different index and it stores just the information from the field marked for Spell suggestion.
It does not have any reference of the document from which it had originated from.
So the filter query with suggester would not work.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing my request is pretty popular. is there another way to implement it?

Comment: If you using a spell suggestion for Did you mean then i dont have much idea. If you providing a type ahead facet.prefix can probably aid you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wanted it, using **fq** is working fine in the version Solr 6.4.1 (and probably higher versions too)

```
http://.../solr/vault/suggest?q=c&fq=BookOwner:3
```